# Can you shut down your computer when your model is being trained on Google Cloud?

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-platform

When you train a model via jupyter notebook in a Google Cloud instance, should you keep your computer on until for the model to finish training? All the computation is done in the cloud but still the code and the notebook is on your browser. So I was a bit curious.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

This is actually more related on Jupyter behaviour than being run on a Google Cloud Instance.

If your process is not terminated in your VM instance, then the kernel is still active and although you close your browser, whatever you are running should still be running. You should be able to therefore access again the notebook and access all variables which had already being defined, however you cannot see any output that was printed to the notebook (if any). In case you need to close your window and want to log events you can see some of the suggestions in the following post:

[Keep Jupyter notebook running after closing browser tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32539832/keep-jupyter-notebook-running-after-closing-browser-tab)

Also [this github issue thread](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1647) could be useful