# Connecting to a running Jupyter kernel with a currently running process

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-console

Over the weekend I had some long processes running in a Jupyter notebook, but the browser window was closed at some point. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36845963/6137760) answer, the process shouldn't have been canceled, but whatever output I would have gotten would be lost. This is okay, as I only need access to the resulting objects from the process. My goal is to connect to the running kernel in the console, and work from there. According to [Jupyter's documentation](https://jupyter-console.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), I should be able to do this with

```
jupyter console --existing
```

But after running this and hanging for a minute I get the following

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyter_console/ptshell.py", line 323, in init_kernel_info
    reply = self.client.get_shell_msg(timeout=1)
  File "/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyter_client/client.py", line 77, in get_shell_msg
    return self.shell_channel.get_msg(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyter_client/blocking/channels.py", line 57, in get_msg
    raise Empty
queue.Empty

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda/envs/py35/bin/jupyter-console", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 267, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 657, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-116>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyter_console/app.py", line 141, in initialize
    self.init_shell()
  File "/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyter_console/app.py", line 114, in init_shell
    client=self.kernel_client,
  File "/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/traitlets/config/configurable.py", line 412, in instance
    inst = cls(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyter_console/ptshell.py", line 272, in __init__
    self.init_kernel_info()
  File "/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyter_console/ptshell.py", line 326, in init_kernel_info
    raise RuntimeError("Kernel didn't respond to kernel_info_request")
RuntimeError: Kernel didn't respond to kernel_info_request
```

Is this occurring because my long-running process is still running on the kernel, or could there be an other issue? Should I be able to connect as expected using the above command when said process is complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution *drumroll*:

I simply needed to run

```
jupyter console --existing
```

in the same directory in which I ran

```
jupyter notebook
```