# Is there a way to reopen a running JupyterLab tab with a output stream?

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-lab

If I run

```
import time
for i in range(999):
    print (i)
    time.sleep(1)
```

close the tab and reopen, it wont show the live output stream.
I checked, its running in the background.

is there a way to come back to a running script after I closed the tab?

video demo:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sioA.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing first: code doesn't stop on tab closing (and you can see it from the log if you are launching JN from Anaconda Prompt). This is a good hint to find a viable solution.

Actually there are many ways to do this, and I'll suggest to dig [this very good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32539832/keep-jupyter-notebook-running-after-closing-browser-tab/44562708) for a lot of other methods.

To me the most *Jupyter Notebook-ish* solution is to use the cell magic `%%capture`.

How to use it:

```
%%capture temp_output
# your running script here
```

Save the Notebook, close the tab, do whatever you want.
Go back to the notebook, open it and:

```
temp_output.show()
```

Will let have your result.